# Control to inform user about job status

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I want make a control to inform user about the job status of some jobs.

I am making a .mdb file with ms access form. I want to add a control inside the form. The control should display the name of report to be made, and their status (finished/canceled), it is best for the status coloured with red/green light, or give them a tick/cross:

[image]

Do you have any idea? Or maybe some simple alternative? At least I cannot find any grid control which allow dynamic addition for each row. I would like to do it in the code because the number of job is unknown, so it is hard to decide a row size for them.

Comment: You wouldn't use a control for this. You probably should use a built-in repeating form.

Answer (score 1):

A subform with conditional formatting applied to one or more of the controls should get you what you want.  Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider one of the following:

- Use table similar to yours but use green check mark for finished jobs and red cross mark for canceled. It could be simple image controls next to textbox/label
- Use one-column structure in which you can make green background for finished and red for canceled. The text in the column would be Job names. This would work if users know what the color means
- Use two separate tables: one - for finished and second - for canceled jobs

Hope this is helpful